# Enable Intellij IDEA support for none-standard characters in java class name

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea, utf

I've pulled [hibernate-orm](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm) and wanted to run some tests to figure out how it works but I couldn't as the following command `[hibernate-orm]$ ./gradlew clean build -Pdb=pgsql` which I copied from readme.md failed with the following message:

```
* What went wrong:
Failed to capture fingerprint of input files for task ':hibernate-core:compileTestJava' property 'source' during up-to-date check.
> Failed to create MD5 hash for file '.../hibernate-orm/hibernate-core/src/test/java/org/hibernate/internal/util/hib3rnat3/C0nst4nts???.java' as it does not exist.
```

I check the source code and find out that it imports class with name [C0nst4nts३](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/test/java/org/hibernate/internal/util/hib3rnat3/C0nst4nts%E0%A5%A9.java) and my IDEA complains that couldn't find such class:

[image]

I am not actually sure that it's valid class name. I check IDEA encodings and ensure that it's UTF-8. So any ideas how I can make it run?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in wrong system locale. It was LANG=C, I set it to "en_US.UTF-8" and not it works well. Hope it will hope to somebody.